# Does Cypress use nghttp2?

Tags: security, cypress, nghttp2

Does [Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress) use nghttp2, either directly or through its dependencies?

there is one vulnerability for this  [CVE-2015-8659](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-8659)
I tried to find it in direct dependency but did not get so asking if anyone can suggest it. The mentioned tag in the vulnerability is 8.2.0